# Bus Routes Algorithm

Tags: algorithm, shortest-path, breadth-first-search

I'm trying to solve the following question:
https://leetcode.com/problems/bus-routes/

> We have a list of bus routes. Each `routes[i]` is a bus route that the i<sup>th</sup> bus repeats forever. For example if `routes[0] = [1, 5, 7]`, this means that the first bus (0<sup>th</sup> indexed) travels in the sequence 1→5→7→1→5→7→1→... forever.
>
> We start at bus stop `S` (initially not on a bus), and we want to go to bus stop `T`. Travelling by buses only, what is the least number of buses we must take to reach our destination? Return -1 if it is not possible.
>
> ### Example:
>
> #### Input:
>
> ```
> routes = [[1, 2, 7], [3, 6, 7]]
> S = 1
> T = 6
> ```
>
> #### Output:
>
> ```
> 2
> ```
>
> ### Explanation:
>
> The best strategy is take the first bus to the bus stop 7, then take the second bus to the bus stop 6.
>
> ### Note:
>
> ```
> 1 <= routes.length <= 500.
> 1 <= routes[i].length <= 500.
> 0 <= routes[i][j] < 10 ^ 6.
> ```

My idea is to treat each stop as a Node. Each node has a color (the bus number), and has a value (the stop number).

This problem would then be converted to a 0-1 BFS shortest path problem.

Here's my code :

```java
class Node {
  int val;
  int color;
  boolean visited;
  int distance;

  public Node(int val, int color) {
    this.val = val;
    this.color = color;
    this.visited = false;
    this.distance = 0;
  }

  public String toString() {
    return "{ val = " + this.val  +  ", color = " + this.color + " ,distance = " + this.distance + "}";
  }
}

class Solution {
    public int numBusesToDestination(int[][] routes, int S, int T) {
      if(S == T) return 0;
      // create nodes
      // map each values node(s)
      // distance between nodes of the same bus, have 0 distance
      // if you're switching buses, the distance is 1
      Map<Integer, List<Node>> adjacency = new HashMap<Integer, List<Node>>();
      int color = 0;
      Set<Integer> colorsToStartWith = new HashSet<Integer>();
      for(int[] route : routes) {
        for(int i = 0; i < route.length - 1; i++) {
          int source = route[i];
          int dest = route[i + 1];
          adjacency.putIfAbsent(source, new ArrayList<Node>());
          adjacency.putIfAbsent(dest, new ArrayList<Node>());
          if(source == S) colorsToStartWith.add(color);
          adjacency.get(source).add(new Node(dest, color));
          adjacency.get(source).add(new Node(source, color));
        }
        if(route[route.length - 1] == S) colorsToStartWith.add(color);
        adjacency.putIfAbsent(route[route.length - 1], new ArrayList<Node>());
        adjacency.get(route[route.length - 1]).add(new Node(route[0], color));
        adjacency.get(route[route.length - 1]).add(new Node(route[route.length - 1], color));
        color++;
      }

      // run bfs
      int minDistance = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
      Deque<Node> q = new LinkedList<Node>();
      Node start = new Node(S, 0);
      start.distance = 1;
      q.add(start);
      boolean first = true;
      boolean found = false;
      while(!q.isEmpty()) {
        Node current = q.remove();
        current.visited = true;
        System.out.println(current);
        for(Node neighbor : adjacency.get(current.val)) {
          if(!neighbor.visited) {
            neighbor.visited = true;
            if(neighbor.color == current.color || current.val == neighbor.val || first) {
              q.addFirst(neighbor);
              neighbor.distance = current.distance;
            } else {
              q.addLast(neighbor);
              neighbor.distance = current.distance + 1;
            }
            if(neighbor.val == T) { 
              minDistance = Math.min(minDistance, neighbor.distance);
            }
          }
        }
        first = false;
      }
      return minDistance == Integer.MAX_VALUE ? -1  : minDistance;      
    }
}
```

I'm not sure why this is wrong.

The following test case fails :

```
Routes = [
    [12,16,33,40,44,47,68,69,77,78,82,86,97],
    [5,8,25,28,45,46,50,52,63,66,80,81,95,97],
    [4,5,6,14,30,31,34,36,37,47,48,55,56,58,73,74,76,80,88,98],
    [58,59],
    [54,56,78,96,98],
    [7,30,35,44,60,87,97],
    [3,5,57,88],
    [3,9,13,15,23,24,28,38,49,51,54,59,63,65,78,81,86,92,95],
    [2,7,16,20,23,46,55,57,93],
    [10,11,15,31,32,48,53,54,57,66,69,75,85,98],
    [24,26,30,32,51,54,58,77,81],
    [7,21,39,40,49,58,84,89],
    [38,50,57],
    [10,57],
    [11,27,28,37,55,56,58,59,81,87,97],
    [0,1,8,17,19,24,25,27,36,37,39,51,68,72,76,82,84,87,89],
    [10,11,14,22,26,30,48,49,62,66,79,80,81,85,89,93,96,98],
    [16,18,24,32,35,37,46,63,66,69,78,80,87,96],
    [3,6,13,14,16,17,29,30,42,46,58,73,77,78,81],
    [15,19,32,37,52,57,58,61,69,71,73,92,93]
]
S = 6
T = 30
```

What is the error in my code that makes this test fail?

Comment: Is this the smallest test-input you can come up with? Try to find a simple failing case and debug it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The example input you give should return 1, since the one-but-last route contains both the source and target bus stop (6 and 30):

```
[3,6,13,14,16,17,29,30,42,46,58,73,77,78,81]
```

I ran [your code with that input](https://repl.it/@trincottrincots/busroutes), and it returns 1, so your solution is rejected for another reason, which then must be a time out.

I see several causes for why your code is not optimal:

- While ideally a BFS should stop when it has found the target node, your version must continue to visit *all* unvisited nodes that are reachable, before it can decide what the solution is. So even if it finds the target on the same route as the source, it will continue to switch routes and so do a lot of unnecessary work, as there is no hope to find a *shorter* path.

  This is not how it is supposed to be. You should take care to perform your search in a way that gives priority to the edges that do not increase the distance, and only when there are no more of those, pick an edge that adds 1 to the distance. If you do it like that you can stop the search as soon as you have found the target.
- A `Node` object is created repeatedly for the same combination of bus stop and "color" (i.e. route). As a consequence, when you later set `visited` to `true`, the duplicate `Node` objects will still have `visited` equal to `false` and so that bus stop will be visited several times with no gain.

  You should make sure to only create new `Node` objects when there is no existing object with such combination yet.
- Edges exist between two consecutive bus stops on the same route, meaning you may need to traverse several edges on the same route before finding the one that is either the target or the right place to switch to another route.

  It would be more efficient to consider a *whole* route a `Node`: routes would be considered connected (with an edge) when they share at least one bus stop. Converting routes to `Set`s of bus stops would make it fast and easy to identify these edges.
- The reflexive edges, from and to the same bus stop, but specifying a color (route), also do not add to efficiency. The main issue you tried to solve with this set up, is to make sure that the first choice of a route is free of charge (is not considered a switch). But that concern is no longer an issue if you apply the previous bullet point.

## Implementation

I chose JavaScript as implementation, but I guess it wont be hard to rewrite this in Java:

```js
function numBusesToDestination (routes, S, T) {
    if (S === T) return 0;
    // Create nodes of the graph
    const nodes = routes;
    // Map bus stops to routes: a map keyed by stops, with each an empty Set as value
    const nodesAtBusStop = new Map([].concat(...routes.map(route => route.map(stop => [stop, new Set]))));
    // ... and populate those empty Sets:
    for (let node of nodes) {
        for (let stop of node) {
            nodesAtBusStop.get(stop).add(node);
        }
    }
    // Build adjacency list of the graph
    const adjList = new Map(nodes.map(node => [node, new Set]));
    for (let [stop, nodes] of nodesAtBusStop.entries()) {
        for (let a of nodes) {
            for (let b of nodes) {
                if (a !== b) adjList.get(a).add(b);
            }
        }
    }
    const startNodes = nodesAtBusStop.get(S);
    const targetNodes = nodesAtBusStop.get(T);
    if (!startNodes || !targetNodes) return -1;
    // BFS
    let queue = [...startNodes];
    let distance = 1;
    let visited = new Set;
    while (queue.length) {
        // Create a new queue for each distance increment
        let nextLevel = [];
        for (let node of queue) {
            if (visited.has(node)) continue;
            visited.add(node);
            if (targetNodes.has(node)) return distance;
            nextLevel.push(...adjList.get(node));
        }
        queue = nextLevel;
        distance++;
    }
    return -1;
};

// I/O handling
(document.oninput = function () {
    let result = "invalid JSON";
    try {
        let routes = JSON.parse(document.querySelector("#inputRoutes").value);
        let S = +document.querySelector("#inputStart").value;
        let T = +document.querySelector("#inputTarget").value;
        result = numBusesToDestination(routes, S, T);
    }
    catch (e) {}
    document.querySelector("#output").textContent = result;
})();
```

```css
#inputRoutes { width: 100% }
```

```html
Routes in JSON format:
<textarea id="inputRoutes">[[1,2,7],[3,6,7]]</textarea><br>
Start: <input id="inputStart" value="1"><br>
Target: <input id="inputTarget" value="6"><br>
Distance: <span id="output"></span>
```